# Syntax Error with print statement after while loop

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I am using Python 2.7 with my Raspberry Pi 3 and getting an error at this print statement:

```
print rc_time(pin_to_circuit)
```

Here is a code snippet from the program:

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

pin_to_circuit=7

def rc_time (pin_to_circuit):
 count=0
 GPIO.setup(pin_to_circuit, GPIO.OUT)
 #some code 
 return count


try:
  while True:
         print rc_time(pin_to_circuit)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  pass
finally:
  GPIO.cleanup()

def main():
 print 'starting...'
 ldrData= rc_time(pin_to_circuit)
 tPayload= "field1=" % ldrData

 while True:
  try:
   publish.single(topic, payload=tPayload, hostname=mqttHost, port=tPort, 
    tls=tTLS, transport= tTransport)

  except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
  except:      
        print: 'Error publishing the data'


#call main
if __name__=='__main__':
 main()
```

Here is the error:

```
File "ldrmqtt.py", line 65
  print rc_time(pin_to_circuit)
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: this is almost certainly the line it points to: `print: 'Error publishing the data'`

Comment: @AnthonySottile But it doesn't give any error there.

Comment: Show the full traceback, please

Comment: Are you completely sure this is Python 2?

Comment: @pycoder Yes, I just checked it. It's Python 2.7.9

Comment: Just tested in Python 2 REPL, it works fine. [repl here](https://repl.it/@pyelias/SO-Test-1)

Comment: @Margo [Edit] your question to include more details, please. Show the error. How you run this, and prove the Python version

Comment: @cricket_007 I just added the full traceback .

Comment: @cricket_007 I used python -V to get the python version

Comment: Yep, you are running on Python 3.

Comment: @cricket_007 I just indented it

Comment: @KlausD. It's Python 3?

Comment: This is a typical error that you get when you use the Python 2 print statement on Python 3. Use print as a function: `print(...)`

Comment: @Klaus Or `print` has been redefined as a function, from futures

Comment: In any case @Margo MQTT is not related to the error, neither is the while loop. If you remove them while you debug the issue and create a [mcve] you might find the problem on your own

Comment: @cricket_007 You can't redefine reserved keywords like `print`.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yeah, that 'import print_function' was the prob. Thanks

Comment: @Klaus How does `from __future__ import print_function` define `print()`? That's basically redefining the behavior of Python 2 `print`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the only way this could occur (if you are really on Python 2.7) is if you have a `from __future__ import print_function`. To fix this, either remove that line or use print as a function.

[evidence](https://repl.it/@pyelias/SO-Test-1)